Firebase Token is not generating in Samsung S23
i am facing weird problem, i have 5 Samsung S23 devices, and FCM token is generating in 3 devices but not generating on other 2. i found some where we have to reset the device, due to security of the device, some times FCM token does not generate.
Please give some light he what can be the root cause of such issue.

I am also experiencing this issue. Did you find any solution?

@Macksly, I'm also experiencing this. Have you find any solution yet?

Sadly I haven't found any solution
